# link for image and html link to a jsp not working

Tags: java, html, jsp, browser, anchor

Here is my login.jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html>  
    <head>  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">  
        <title>Login Page</title>  
    </head>  
    <body>  

        <div align="center">  
            <img src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/image/asd.jpg">  
        </div>  
        <div id=loginFormDiv align="center">  
            <form name="loginform" method="post" action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/login">  
        <br><br>  
            <table align="center"><tr><td><h2>Login Authentication</h2></td></tr></table>  
            <table width="300px" align="center" style="border:1px solid #000000;background-color:#efefef;">  
                <tr><td colspan=2></td></tr>  
                <tr><td colspan=2> </td></tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td><b>Login Name</b></td>  
                    <td><input type="text" name="userName" value=""></td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td><b>Password</b></td>  
                    <td><input type="password" name="password" value=""></td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td></td>  
                    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr><td colspan=2> </td></tr>  
            </table>  
        </form>  
    </div>  
    <div id="changePasswordLinkId" align="center">  
        <a href="./ChangePassword.jsp">Change Password</a>  
    </div>  
 </body>  
 </html>
```

Here when I load this page for the first time the image as well as the link to another jsp  with div id   ="changePasswordLinkId" doesn't work. The image is not shown and clicking the anchor link displays the login page    again.however if I login once and use the back button of the browser they work. 
Also, the console log from google chrome gives a warning :- "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "htt_p://localhot:8080/Tool/image/asd.jpg>". ChangePassword.jsp:12"

Plz help me on this. I will be  very thankful.
Thanks In advance.

Comment: when you load the page, do you see any 404 not found, in your browser ? (using firebug or chrome developer tools)

Comment: No, The only thing I see is same page loading again. i.e., I click on "Change password" and the above page(code given above) gets loaded again.

Comment: Did you try to analyze the browser console when the image does not load? what is the rendered html ?

Comment: That shows the resource doesn't exist. however the same image address and "change Password" link work when I login and use the browser back button to namvigate back. i.e, the image is available then and "change password" link work perfectly. However on the console of Google chrome I can see this warning - "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/Tool/image/asd.jpg".                ChangePassword.jsp:12"

Comment: when chrome says "the resource doesn't exist", can you try to copy the related url (from chrome console) and paste it in the url bar, and tell us what it displays

Comment: It shows the login page whose code is given above only. Totally unexpected...  n its killing me... :(

Comment: please follow me here, when img does not display, the browser (chrome) normally says: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" and gives you the url of the img, please copy that url in a new tab and tell what happens

Comment: Here the browser doesn't give status 404 it just doesn't display the image. and the image url loads the login page again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out, it works fine - the first time.

Which server are you using?

How are you deploying the jsp?

Comment: I am using tomcat version 7, eclipse IDE to develop the app. I am developing the jsp by using the default right click way of developing the app.

Comment: I'm new to eclipse...I don't know how to do that. What I did: Created a new file in a Dynamic Web Project, pasted your code, ran my ant deploywar target, switched to tomcat7 on localhost in firefox and entered the url for the jsp. Worked perfectly the first time - your code is solid, eclipse...maybe not so much.

Comment: Thanks Ray for your efforts. I am aware there isnot any error in the code. it should work but something is there that is stopping it in th first run.

Comment: Maybe add the eclipse tag to your question? (what I meant before is that your eclipse is possibly not set up 'right' and is the root of your woes)

Answer (score 0):

Java EE application servers can host more than one "webapp".
The portion of the URI just after the port (shown in bold) is known as the contextPath for a webapp.

In this case 'index.html' is in root directory of the webapp called myWebApp.

In those links you've posted, the developer (rightly) built the relative links by reading the contextPath from the request object. This allows for the renaming of the webapp without the need to alter every link in the app.

Comment: Thanks emrerme, But the thing still remains that why the image and "change Password" link doesn't work when I first run the app on the server. however once I login and go back the image is available and I can click "change Password" link and navigate to ChangePassword.jsp. The question here is the link is not working on first run?